# From Outlook 2019, how can I most orderly forward 100 emails?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

A government agency has asked me to forward at least 100 emails to them. What are the most sprucest ways? The following aren't —

1. Printing each email as a PDF wastes space. I don't know why, but Adobe PDF and Microsoft Print to PDF adds too much white space.
2. Clicking 'Forward' 100 times undeniably wastes too much time, and would engulf the recipient's inbox! I loathe to have to move 100 emails to another folder.

Comment: Being you’re dealing with a government agency. How have *they* asked for you to do it??

Answer (score 1):

This should be rather simple, if you want to
[Forward multiple messages as a combined single message](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/forward-multiple-messages-as-a-combined-single-message-2de65840-c2c9-4024-b8f1-fb32d1ef2a1b).

Just select all the emails, then on the Home menu click Forward.
This will open new message with the selected messages as attachments.

Another possibility is to drag the 100 selected messages into some disk folder.
This will create 100 files of type `.msg`. You may now zip up all the files
and send them as one email.
The recipient will need to unpack and drag the files back into his Outlook
folder.